# How to make element positioned according to another element?

Tags: css, fullcalendar, css-position, react-datepicker

I have a calendar icon above a fullcalendar, when I click on the icon, a react-datepicker will be appeared.

My css :

```
.react-datepicker {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -42.5px;
  right: -43px;
}
```

My codesandbox is : https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-tqdng

When I run it, I get :

[image]

I want the react-datepicker will be appeared completely.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I think that, at some point of the css, you have an overflow hidden applied in a parent element which is clipping the calendar. Or the table below has an higher z-index. It's difficult to say without a short self-contained example

Comment: @fcalderan How can I resolve it ?

Comment: sharing a code snippet that shows the issue could be useful as a first step

Comment: @fcalderan I edited my post by adding the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-tqdng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the z-index of the full calendar is higher than the date picker or date picker is lower than the full calendar.

I added this in the style.css and it does the trick:

```css
.fc {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure :

- Parent of the Calendar has higher z-index than, whatever is below and doesn't have overflow: hidden
- stuff below the Calendar doesn't have transform or opacity (which can affect the stacking order)
- If both Calendar and stuff below are siblings, make sure the Calendar has higher z-index

Comment: I try to add overflow:hidden but, it doesn't working. I edited my post by adding the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-tqdng